# calculus true or false

Tags: calculus

I have got about 40 different equations to decide if true or false.
Although it is optional homework i am having trouble with part of them, every thing i write i have tried to solve by my self.

1) $$\lim_{x\to 0} {\sin ax\over bx} = {a\over b} \textrm{ for every } {b \neq 0} $$

what i thought here is that its can only be true when $a=0$ so if $a\neq 0$ it is false
so i dont know how to decide if the equation is right or wrong

2) $$\lim_{x\to \infty} {\sin x\over x} = {1} \; $$

it is known that $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to 0} {\sin x\over x} = {1} \; $ so does $ 0\in\infty$ ?
i am so confused about this one

3) $$\lim_{x\to \infty} {(\sqrt {x^2 +x}-x) } = {1\over 2} \; $$
4)$$\lim_{x\to -\infty} {(\sqrt {x^2 +x}-x) } = {1\over 2} \; $$

Thats pretty much the same i wasnt sure how to approach it, i need a hint.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The second one is wrong, the limit should be 0

Answer (score 1):

2) this one is wrong, since $-1<sin(x)<1$ the numerator is bounded, while the denominator is not, so their ratio approaches 0 as $x$ approaches $\infty$

3)rationalize to obtain $\frac{x}{x+\sqrt{x+x^2}}$, can you solve it from here?

4)this limit is also wrong, just substitute $-\infty$ to obtain $\infty+\sqrt{\infty}=\infty$

Answer (score 0):

The first one: $\frac{sinax}{bx}=\frac{1}{b}*\frac{sinax}{x}=\frac{a}{b}*\frac{sinax}{ax}$ Now if you take the limit $x→0$ on that second fraction, what do you conlcude?